# calling R function "optim" from C

Tags: c, r

I am new to C.

I am trying to use optim function from C. According to "Writing R Extension" Section 5.8, the Nelder Mead method requires 16 arguments:

```
void nmmin(int n, double *xin, double *x, double *Fmin, optimfn fn,
           int *fail, double abstol, double intol, void *ex,
           double alpha, double beta, double gamma, int trace,
           int *fncount, int maxit);
```

In my understanding, unlike R which accepts default values in arguments of functions, C requires users of the function to provide all the arguments.
Although I read optim hep page, I still have troubles understanding the meaning of some of these arguments i.e.:

- fail
- intol
- ex
- fncount

I highly appreciate if anyone can direct me where the descriptions of all the arguments are.

p.s.

The followings are the arguments that I figure out what they are:

- n: the number of parameters,
- xin: the initial value of the parameter
- x: storage for the final parameters on exit, with fi
- Fmin: the final value of the objective function
- fn: the objective function
- abstol: absolute tolerance
- maxit: the maximum number of iterations
- trace: Non-negative integer. If positive, tracing information on the progress of the optimization is produced.

The followings are some arguments specific for the Nelder Mead method:

- alpha:  R optim function uses = 1
- beta:   R optim function uses = 0.5
- gamma:  R optim function uses = 2 
  (I found these default values by reading the optim function codes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fail - receives true if the function failed

intol - user-initialized conversion tolerance

ex - data to pass to the optimization function (fn)

alpha - reflection factor

beta - contraction and reduction factor

gamma - extension factor

fncount - receives the number of times the optimization function was called in the iteration loop

You can see how these parameters are used here:

http://fossies.org/dox/R-2.15.1/optim_8c_source.html#l00674

For instance, intol is used like so:

```
convtol = intol * (fabs(f) + intol);
if (trace) Rprintf("  Scaled convergence tolerance is %g\n", convtol);
```

There are some more details about the Nelder-Mead algorithm here, with Pascal code:

http://books.google.com/books?id=M9hTn3UAheQC&pg=PA173

(Compact Numerical Methods for Computers: Linear Algebra and Function Minimisation by John C. Nash)